# An affix riddle to dip into

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a great part of what can be found in bird cemeteries
> My infix is a shortened form of a capturing device's name
> My suffix sounds like a great quantity of matter, but prefers to dig
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> **GUACAMOLE** - a sauce or 'dip', as per the title.

*My prefix is a great part of what can be found in bird cemeteries*

> Your prefix is **GUA**, which is the majority of the word '[GUANO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guano)', i.e. accumulated excrement of birds, commonly found in places where they live, die and gather.

*My infix is a shortened form of a capturing device's name*

> Your infix is **CAM**, short for CAMERA, a device which captures images.

*My suffix sounds like a great quantity of matter, but prefers to dig*

> Your suffix is **MOLE**, a word which is both the [SI unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)) for amount of a substance, and the name of a burrowing animal (which 'prefers to dig').

Altogether:

> GUA + CAM + MOLE (with overlap) = **GUACAMOLE**